# How to show only the link of an uploaded file, not its location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have used paperclip to allow me to upload files to a rails application. Everything works and the file is uploaded, but instead of seeing a link to the actual file itself I see the location of it within the systems folder of the rails project.

I'm guessing its either a routing issue or I need to create a link to the file in question. However, I would like to hide the location of the file itself, and only see the link displayed.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to hide the actual path of the file in the server, right?

You can achieve that using send_file (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) in  a normal controller.

You will still need to do something to protect the download using the real path.

Comment: OK.  Ive checked out the link and its not really what Im after.

The situation is, I upload a text file and then in the show view, it displays the path of the file rather than a link to the file itself.  Ive tried linking to the file name in the show view, but this doesnt work.  The one thing I havent tried is setting up a link, calling that link the file name, and then setting the path for that link to the path where the file is stored.  I cant see how this is necessary though, because normally its enough to refer to the array where the information is stored, right?

Comment: Would I be better off using Carrier Wave?

Comment: Ah.  I have looked more closely at the link that robertokl furnished me with and I think it may indeed be what Im looking for.  Thankyou.